# Flutter: iOS - The new IAP functionality is not working with older products

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have Flutter iOS app with "IAP Product" functionality. I have created 4 "Consumable product" on appStore and uploaded new binary to store. But there we missed some functionality part for that reason products are not able to purchase multiple times.

So we made changes in our code and added missing functionality. But it is not worked with old IAP product which we are created previously. So we created new products on appStore and our code is working as expected with new IAP products.

But I want that should also work with old product as well.

Is there any way to achieve this?

### Updated

See, we wanted to buy single product multiple time so for that we have created the `Consumable IAP` product but because of some missing functionality we are not able to buy single product multiple time. So we done some changes and build was uploaded.

With new build we are able to fetch the old as well as new products and we are able to make purchases.

**For New Product** : We are able to purchase single product multiple times as we expected.

**For Old Product** : We are not able to purchase single product multiple times. Only one time purchase is available for old product.

I want to buy single product multiple times for both old and new product.

Can it be possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "But it is not worked with old IAP product"?
Can you fetch old IAP products? 
Can you make a purchase request?
What happens after doing a purchase request?
any exceptions?

Comment: please see updated question.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.